# Let's have a [migration] out of the system

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migration) tag is a meta-tag. A migration is by definition something from a source to a destination. Since the tag doesn't specify that source and destination, that makes it a meta-tag.

It has currently 4478 questions and is, unfortunately, growing. We need to get rid of this tag. When editing, we should simply replace it with the appropriate tag(s) for the source and target of the migration.

So, let the [migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migration) tag emigrate from Stack Overflow.

Comment: I disagree that it's a meta tag, but I think it *is* too broad for use.

Comment: You make a good point but I personally think the migration tag is useful. I can use it to see all of the migration questions and then I can scroll through them until I find some languages that I know. Removing the migration tag means that it wouldn't be as easy to see at first glance whether a question is referring to *communication* between two languages or *migrating data* between the two

Comment: For one, the 130 questions in [tag:migration] in [[migration] + [entity-framework]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migration+entity-framework) can probably be migrated to [tag:code-first-migrations].

Comment: I don't think it should be called a meta-tag. According to [this](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/434/please-zap-the-meta-tags-and-dependent-tags) definition it is not: "...meta-tags do not describe the content of the question. They describe some other aspect of the question, like the author's skill level, or the author's motivation for asking it, or generally what "kind" of question it is (poll, how-to, etc.)."

Comment: @Anders Your definition does not make it a meta-tag. Another one might: "**If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.** Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective], and [best-practices], are useless by themselves — they tell you nothing at all about the content of the question." (Source: [The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)) Still debatable, I agree.

Comment: Dilemma. [migration] *only* is quite useless, [migration]+[source]+[destination] looks valuable (Reece's comment). But then, Chop's comment kicks in (*if it can't ...* ). I suggest we are not too formal here, leave it in, and promote the use of [migration]+[source]+[destination] (Some cleaning up to do?)

Comment: @JanDoggen: The problem of [migration]+[source]+[destination] is that it's impossible to distinguish (in search) from [migration]+[destination]+[source]; a specific tag such as [migration-c-c++] would indicate the direction of the migration.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I did not strictly mean [source][destination] in that order. I should have written [endpoint1][endpoint2].

Comment: @JanDoggen: My point, however is that a migration from A to B can be vastly different from a migration from B to A; for example the Go team developed a tool to move from C to Go, making it relatively easy, whereas there is no tool that I know of to move from Go to C.

Comment: I misread this question completely, and after reading the currently-5-vote-having answer I disagree that migration is a meta tag! Or maybe I still misunderstand the tag!! Among all questions about code there are migration questions (e.g. migration from mySQL to postgres) and there are non-migration questions (e.g. why are all the facets of my polyhedron invisible in this OpenGL program?) So to me the tag DOES tell you something about the question. Like it could mean that the question is going to be a boring migration question instead of potentially an interesting rendering question.

Comment: My misreading was, the tag was somehow about migrating questions between 'exchanges' because that would definitely be meta.

Answer (score 5):

Migration is a bit too broad of a concept and should broken down a bit.  Here is a proposal to cleanup the tag.

**Tags to burn as being too broad:**

- [migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migration) x4775
- [migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migrate) x435
- [migrating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migrating) x58
- [code-migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-migration) x47

**Replacement tags by concept:**

- **Language1** to **Language2** => [code-translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-translation)

  Migrating from one programming language to a different programming language.
- **Lang1 + Env1** to **Lang1 + Env2** => [porting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/porting)

  Migrating code to another environment or another version of the same language.
- **DB1** to **DB2** => [database-migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-migration)

  Migrating from one database system to a different database system.
- **Something Something Entity Framework** => [code-first-migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-first-migrations)
- **Smaller, specific topics**:

  - [rails-migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rails-migrations)
  - [core-data-migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core-data-migration)
  - [ef-migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-migrations)
  - [django-migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-migrations)
  - [tfs-migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs-migration)
  - [version-control-migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version-control-migration)
  - [doctrine-migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doctrine-migrations)
  - [laravel-migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-migrations)
  - [yii-migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii-migrations)
- ???

---

**Questionable tags:**

- [data-migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-migration) x665 - Possibly a lot of duplicates with [database-migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-migration)

Comment: What is [code-first-migrations], is that the generic example for the list below it? If so, please [edit] the layout.

Comment: Maybe we should leave [porting] out, it is going to be confused with [code-translation]. The difference is clear *with your description* but the tag names are not self-explanatory enough.

Comment: +1. Some of these could still be considered meta-tags, but it's a lot better than "migration".

Comment: I'm just listing other already-in-use tags that seem reasonable.

Comment: @JanDoggen I don't know anything about Entity Framework, so I left the description blank.