# Migrate [migrating] tag to [migration], [migrate], and [database-migration]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

I stumbled upon the [migrating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migrating) tag today; it has 62 questions, no tag wiki or usage guideline, and looking at the questions in that tag, no common theme other than a variation of the word "migrate". There are three tags that I think these questions can be moved into, [migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migration), [migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migrate), and [database-migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-migration). The usage guidelines of those tags are:

---

[migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migration)

An action of moving between major version of any framework, product or language, or, just as commonly, alteration to the data schema of an application. This might involve modifying existing data to make it work with the new version.

---

[migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migrate)

Migration is the process of moving data from container to another. This includes migration to and from physical containers (e.g. hard disks) and migration to and from logical containers.

Migration often involves some form of reorganization of the data.

Physical migration includes (but is not limited to):

- moving data from an old hard disk to a newer one
- moving data from one server to another

Logical migration includes (but is not limited to):

- migrating data from one database system to another (e.g. Oracle 10g to MySQL 5)
- migrating existing web applications from one web server to another
- migrating a cell phones contact list to another cell phone

In contrast to [replication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/replication), the data held in the original system after the migration process has been successfully completed is not necessarily used any more.

---

[database-migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-migration)

the process of transferring data between storage types, formats, or computer systems. Also refers to migrating the database from one vendor to another, or to upgrading the version of the database software.

---

All three of these are clearly defined (though broad, [as pointed out here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302896/2856441)), and all the questions in [migrating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migrating) seems to fit nicely in them. Does this migration of [migrating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migrating) to [migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migration), [migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migrate), and [database-migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-migration) make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would get rid of it. Many of the questions seem to fit nicely into the three categories, so I don't see any reason to keep up a fourth tag, especially with no description even though it's been there for several years.

I would maybe even go further and change [migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migrate) to [migrate-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migrate-data) since it's about that clearly. I'm not sure if the autocomplete will search inside words, if not then [database-migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-migration) should at least have a synonyme of [migrate-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migrate-database).

[migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migration) should be [migrate-version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migrate-version) maybe?